# Obiee 12c - few ldap users fail to sign in analytics

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee, tooling

i am using obiee 12c in production and Active Directory ldap server entegrated for authentication. almost all users are able to login analytics but few of these users cannot login. the following error appearing in the screen "The specified credentials could not be authenticated ". I tried to regenerate user GUIDs according to following documents. https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/BIMIG/GUID-E2ABAAA2-FFA2-453F-9C42-4F00807B4708.htm#BIMIG-GUID-E2ABAAA2-FFA2-453F-9C42-4F00807B4708

I set the BI component's log level to Finest and enable debug security option. I examined acces log, bi server diagnostic log and sawlog files, but i can not see any log that contains any failure information about the failed LDAP user.

Could you help me about this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a) That link is invalid since GUIDs do not exist anymore. The documentation shouldn't include that step anymore.

b) Logging the BI components won't show you anything. You need to up up the OPSS logging.